# How do I view the IPs with remote access to my MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql

We have a dedicated server with MySQL.  Our developer has granted remote access to certain IPs. I want to query to see a list of IPs that have been granted access.  I can't find any documentation on the net that tells you exactly how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the show grants function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-grants.html

Comment: Thank you.  If I simply type "SHOW GRANTS;" I basically get this back: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*67F18FEF465DB3AF32700934AD190D0420A05E3' WITH GRANT OPTION
(I changed a few digits for security).  Is this "Password" really the IP address?

Comment: No, the IP is "localhost", e.g. root@localhost

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I guess there are no remote ips that have been granted access in this case.

Comment: Might not have been added to the root user.  Do  you know of any other users as you need to explicitly specify the user.

Comment: Well if other usernames exist, I am not aware of them.  However, it seems like simply "SHOW GRANTS;" would show the grants for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a statement like this

```
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.users;
```